# Is Amazon Route 54 mandatory for SSL enabling on EC2?

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, https, ssl-certificate

I am hosting a spring boot application on EC2 server from AWS.
As per many links, configuring a load balancer is the way, but I have a single server and don't need any load balancing, I prefer to keep my network simple.
Is the load balancer a must? Or I am still able to simply open port 8443 on the same instance and use it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use some form of a load balancer for you backend application. As a small example of what nginx would do is buffer requests to your backend application, so you will not have a connection open if it is slow. It can also help you serve static files, etc.

Case in point - instead of builtin Amazon load balancer, you can use, as a sample, nginx, and nginx is integrated with lets encrypt: https://letsencrypt.org/ (they have good instructions about how to get it running).

The 2 problems you will face now is DNS (If you have a domain name - registrar sometimes provides that) and that EC2 has a floating IP - which you can configure to be static.

I hope this answers the question completely.